# Returning the number of smiles in a sentence + 1 in a function

Tags: python

Word problem:

> Spies must take care that the information conveyed in a text message does not fall into the wrong hands. A text acknowledgement is validated by the number of smiley faces it contains - in other words, the number of times it contains the string `":)"`. The proper reply to each text should contain exactly one more smiley face than the received text, and no other information. The reply will consist of only the correct number of instances of the string `":)"`, separated by single white spaces (and with no leading or trailing spaces).
> Create a function to formulate and return the reply.
>
> Example Input and Output:
>
> In: `"hey important info to follow :)"`
> Out: `":) :)"`
>
> In: `"have u made contact?"`
> Out: `":)"`

I was able to solve the word problem with a print statement, but the problem is, I need to turn it into a function using `return`. I used `end= " "` to make it print on the same line but you can't return that.

```
def reply(s: str) -> str:
    for i in range(s.count(':)') + 1):
        return ":)"

print(reply("hey important info to follow :)"))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can solve this by multiplying the return string by `s.count(':)') + 1`

```
def reply(s: str) -> str:
    return ":) " * (s.count(':)') + 1)
    
print(reply("hey important info to follow :)"))
```

The Output will be:

```
:) :)
```

Comment: I need it separated by a single white space.
Thanks for the help

Comment: @Underleague you just need to ad a space in the return, return ":)" -> return ":) " I just edited the answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your solution is that when you use return the function stops running so it will never return more than one ':)'.

This solution works for me:

```
def reply(s):
    total_smiles = s.count(':)')
    output = ':) ' * (total_smiles + 1)

    # remove whitespace at the end and return
    return output[:-1]


message = "hey important info to follow :)"
response = reply(message)
print(response)
```

Comment: I can't have it end with a space at the end of the string

Comment: This line removes the space at the end before returning the result.

Comment: return output[:-1]

Answer (score 0):

```py
def reply(s: str) -> str:
    for i in range(s.count(':)') + 1):
        return ":)"
```

*return "exits the function or ends it"*

You'll have to count then return, or, in other words, take your return out of the loop.

First I used a for loop like you did, then I used a generator statement because it adds readability to the code.

```py
def reply(s):
    words = s.split()
    count = 1 
    for word in words:
        if ":)" in word  or "(:" in word:
            count += 1

    # or use generator
    count = sum(1 for word in words if ":)" in word) + 1

    return " ".join(":)" for _ in range(count))


print(reply("hey important info to follow :)"))
# >> :) :)
```